# How to update a column in one dataframe based on another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am needing to see how to update one column in a data frame where the employeeID matches that of another data frame.

For example:

```
df1 > 

empID     salary
1         10000
2         15000
3         0

df2 >

empID     salary2
1         10000
2         15000
3         20000
```

I am needing to see how to update it where df1$salary = 0, then update it where df1$empID = df2$empID.

I tried this but received "No such column: salary2" error :

```
df1$salary <- ifelse(df1$salary == 0,sqldf("UPDATE df1 SET salary = salary2 WHERE df1.empID = df2.empID"),df1$salary)
```

Comment: In SQL update updates a table rather than returning a value.  You need `sqldf(c("update ...", "select * from df1"))` to actually return something or else instead of using `update` use the appropriate SQL `select` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do

```
#find empID in df1 where salary is 0
inds <- df1$empID[df1$salary == 0]

#match empID with df2 and get respective salary and update df1
df1$salary[inds] <- df2$salary2[match(inds, df2$empID)]
df1
#  empID salary
#1     1  10000
#2     2  15000
#3     3  20000
```

This should also work if you have multiple entries with 0 in `df1`.

We can do the same using `ifelse` like

```
ifelse(df1$salary == 0, df2$salary2[match(df1$empID, df2$empID)], df1$salary)
```

Comment: I see, is there any way I can implement this within my ifelse statement though? There is other conditions I am checking for as well with the real dataframe that I did not include in my sample code.

Comment: @jwalls91 updated the post using `ifelse` approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with merge,

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = 'empID'), 
               salary = replace(salary, salary == 0, salary2[salary == 0]), 
               salary2 = NULL)

#  empID salary
#1     1  10000
#2     2  15000
#3     3  20000
```

You can also use `ifelse` instead of `replace` for salary, i.e.

```
salary = ifelse(salary == 0, salary2, salary)
```